# i am working with a userscript here and i'm trying to bypass a linkvertise

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

im new to coding i dont know how to write javascript i only know how to change a few things like values and stuff i am trying to bypass linkvertise but the website the linkvertise redirects me to is invalid unless i wait 15 seconds i found code to make it think i have waited 15 seconds when in reality its only 1 second (i dont even know if it actually does that or not because i haven't tested it) `(function() {setTimeout(() => {console.log("Redirecting")}, 15100);`

and i am trying to put it inside of this code `!async function(){"use strict";let e=new XMLHttpRequest;e.responseType="json",e.open("GET",https://bypass.bot.nu/bypass2?url=${document.location.href.slice(0,-1)},!0),e.onload=function(n){4===e.readyState&&(document.location.href=this.response.destination)},e.send(null)}();` to make it bypass the linkvertise and make it think i waited 15 seconds and when i try to put it in the code it doesn't work so can someone put it inside for me and fix the code that makes it think i waited 15 seconds if there is anything to fix in it.

this is the link of where i got the code that makes it think i waited 15 seconds that i dont even know if it makes it think i waited 15 seconds https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/450331-krnl-bypass/code

and this is the code i am trying to put it in https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/435099-linkvertise